# confused about %c and ASCII codes

Tags: c, ascii, asciiencoding

Why would `printf("%c ", 2293552);` print `0`?

ASCII values are from 0 to 127
I know this must be some cyclic thing but I want a clear explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number `2293552` corresponds to `0x22ff30`. When `printf` interprets it as ASCII, it ignores all bits beyond the last eight bits containing `0x30`, which is the code for `'0'`.

From the C99 standard:

> 7.19.1.6.8 -- `%c`: If no `l` length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

Comment: Hah! You beat me to the answer, but I beat you to the standard quote :D (10k only)

Comment: btw, what is the l length modifier?

Comment: And where can i find more or rather whole of the C99 standard document? Is this it? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: haha yes that link is it. L for long. thank you the documentation helped.

Comment: @ronnieaka Yes, that's the pdf from which I quoted. And yes, the `l` is lowercase `L`, for "long".

Answer (score 0):

Likely `%c` is using only the low-order byte of your argument, which is `2293552 & 255 = 48 = '0'`.